# Binary Min Heap : Printing unstored values

Tags: c++, heap

I have a binary heap implementation which goes like this :
I have to figure out the reason for wrong output shown at the end of the code.

Also do I need to delete `myminheap` object after printing it is popping out elements one by one !

heap.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class Heap
{
  public:
    Heap() {}
    ~Heap() {}

    vector <int> heap;
    int left(int parent);
    int right(int parent);
    int parent(int child);
    int size()                  {return heap.size();}
    void print();
};

class MinHeap : public Heap
{
  private:
    void heapify_up(int index);
    void heapify_down(int index);

  public:
    MinHeap() {}
    ~MinHeap() {}

    int pop_min();
    void insert(int element);
};

class MaxHeap : public Heap
{
  private:
    void heapify_up(int index);
    void heapify_down(int index);

  public:
    MaxHeap() {}
    ~MaxHeap() {}

    int pop_max();
    void insert(int element);
};
```

heap.cc

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

#include "heap.h"

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
int Heap::left(int parent)
{
    int i = (parent << 1) + 1;  //2 * parent + 1    read more on bit shifts
    return (i < heap.size()) ? i : -1;
}

int Heap::right(int parent)
{
    int i = (parent << 1) + 2;
    return (i < heap.size()) ? i : -1;
}

int Heap::parent(int child)
{
    if(child){
        int i = (child >> 1) - 1;
        return i;
    }
    else return -1;
}

void Heap::print()
{
    vector<int>::iterator i = heap.begin();
    cout << "Heap = ";
    while(i != heap.end()){
        cout << *i << " ";
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
int MinHeap::pop_min()
{
    int min = heap.front();
    heap[0] = heap[heap.size() - 1];
    heap.pop_back();
    heapify_down(0);
    return min;
}

void MinHeap::insert(int element)
{
    heap.push_back(element);
    heapify_up(heap.size() - 1);
}

void MinHeap::heapify_up(int index)
{
    while(index > 0 && parent(index) >= 0 && heap[parent(index)] > heap[index]){
        int temp = heap[index];
        heap[index] = heap[parent(index)];
        heap[parent(index)] = temp;
        index = parent(index);
    }
}

void MinHeap::heapify_down(int index)
{
    int child = left(index);

    if(child > 0 && right(index) > 0 && heap[child] > heap[right(index)])
        child = right(index);

    if(heap[index] > heap[child]){
        int temp = heap[child];
        heap[child] = heap[index];
        heap[index] = temp;
        heapify_down(child);
    }
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
int MaxHeap::pop_max()
{
    int max = heap.front();
    heap[0] = heap[heap.size() - 1];
    heap.pop_back();
    heapify_down(0);
    return max;
}

void MaxHeap::insert(int element)
{
    heap.push_back(element);
    heapify_up(heap.size() - 1);
}

void MaxHeap::heapify_up(int index)
{
    while(index > 0 && parent(index) >= 0 && heap[parent(index)] < heap[index]){
        int temp = heap[index];
        heap[index] = heap[parent(index)];
        heap[parent(index)] = temp;
        index = parent(index);
    }
}

void MaxHeap::heapify_down(int index)
{
    int child = left(index);

    if(child > 0 && right(index) > 0 && child < right(index))
        child = right(index);

    if(heap[index] < heap[child]){
        int temp = heap[child];
        heap[child] = heap[index];
        heap[child] = temp;
        heapify_down(child);
    }
}
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//              test program
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
int main(){
    // Create the heap
    MinHeap* myminheap = new MinHeap();
    myminheap->insert(700);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(500);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(100);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(800);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(200);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(400);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(900);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(1000);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(300);
    myminheap->print();
    myminheap->insert(600);
    myminheap->print();

    // Get priority element from the heap
    int heapSize = myminheap->size();
    for ( int i = 0; i < heapSize; i++ )
        cout << "Get min element = " << myminheap->pop_min() << endl;

    return 1;
}
```

this gives garbled output as shown below :

```
Heap = 700 
Heap = 700 500 
Heap = 100 500 700 
Heap = 100 500 700 800 
Heap = 100 200 700 800 500 
Heap = 100 200 700 800 500 400 
Heap = 100 200 700 800 500 400 900 
Heap = 100 200 700 800 500 400 900 1000 
Heap = 100 200 700 300 500 400 900 1000 800 
Heap = 100 200 700 300 500 400 900 1000 800 600 
Get min element = 100
Get min element = 200
Get min element = 300
Get min element = 500
Get min element = 73
Get min element = 400
Get min element = 600
Get min element = 700
Get min element = 800
Get min element = 900
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two bugs; the code below fixes them (and I have changed the bit shifts back to mult/div - that makes no difference. Why would one want to use shifts when the natural expression is mult/div by 2 is beyond me. If you are thinking optimization then, well). What the bugs are, I leave that as an exercise ....

```
// Num 1
int Heap::parent(int child)
{
    if(child > 0){
        int i = (child / 2);
        return i;
    }
    else return -1;
}

// Num 2
void MinHeap::heapify_down(int index)
{
    int child = left(index);

    if(child > 0 && right(index) > 0 && heap[child] > heap[right(index)])
        child = right(index);

    if(child > 0 && heap[index] > heap[child]){
        int temp = heap[child];
        heap[child] = heap[index];
        heap[index] = temp;
        heapify_down(child);
    }
}
```

And you have to delete the myminheap. Popping elements one by one does not mean automatic destruction of the container when the element count in container reaches 0.